# How to get Information of Stores

Tags: prestashop

I need your help

How to get the information of the stores in **Store Contacts**?

For example: `$categories = Category::getCategories($context->language->id);`

I need that to display the opening hours in mobile application

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the Stores like this (you can simplify the sql query if you want if you have only one country for example):

```
    $stores = Db::getInstance()->executeS('
        SELECT s.*, cl.name country
        FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'store s
        '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('store', 's').'
        LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'country_lang cl ON (cl.id_country = s.id_country)
        WHERE s.active = 1 AND cl.id_lang = '.(int)$this->context->language->id);
```

then you could loop through the stores and get the hours like this:

```
foreach ($stores as $key => $store) {
  $hours = Tools::unSerialize($store['hours']);
}
```

this will return an array from [0] Monday to [6] Sunday with the strings you entered in the backend as values

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have the error= "Class 'Stores' not found in".          I guess I should add the class to some file

Comment: Still not function. I have this error "Call to undefined method Store::getStores()".

Comment: oh woops, got confused - this would have worked hat `getStores()` been in the class, unfortunately it's not so you will have to copypasta a little from the StoresController - please see my updated answer.